# Undefined Indexed Variable

Tags: core-language, tensors, index, indexed-variable, indexing

I searched already a lot about indexed Variables, and it tends to be the most applicable way to use tensor notation. But I am having a hard time to solve for undefined indexed variables:

Here my stylized problem:

```
F := Table[f[i], {i, 1, n}];
```

The Derivative gives the correct answer if applied for a specified i=1

```
D[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100}], f[1]]
```

=1

If I want to solve more generally let say $ i \in [1, 100] $

```
D[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100}], f[i]]
```

=0

Obviously does not work, how can I solve such a problem generally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The variable `i` is a dummy one. The evaluated expression:

```
Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 10}]

f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4] + f[5] + f[6] + f[7] + f[8] + f[9] + f[10]
```

contains no explicit variable `f[i]`, hence, the result is 0.

Try to first `Inactivate` the sum, and only then to calculate the derivative:

```
expr1 = D[Inactivate[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100}], Sum], f[i]]
```

The result is

[image]

Now let us activate it and select a certain value of i:

```
Activate[expr1] /. i -> 20

(*  1   *)
```

Now, one can combine all that into a function, like this:

```
dif[f_, j_] := (D[Inactivate[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100}], Sum], f[i]] // 
     Activate) /. i -> j;
```

Let us check it up:

```
dif[g, 30]

(*  1  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast help!
I see that this workaround works good for that specific case. In my field, however, I am exposed quite a lot to unspecified indexed variables. Is there maybe a more direct way i.e to put a placeholder on the specific dummy variable place. Something like:
D[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100}], f[0<i<100]]
Or:
D[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100}], f[i_PositiveInteger]]
?

Comment: This way seems to be (1) quite direct and (2) rather flexible. Another thing that from your example I cannot imagine other terms that you need to treat. You had in mind probably - a more short way? Not that I know. The only approach that seems me reasonable is to help Mma a bit. For example, as a first step calculate the derivative of a single term on the screen prior of doing the summation `(*step1*) expr2=D[expr1,f[i]]`. As a second one, make a summation on the screen.`(*step2*) Sum[expr2,{i,1,100}]]`

Comment: (A corrected comment. Discard the previous one) This way seems to be (1) quite direct and (2) rather flexible. Another thing that from your example I cannot imagine other terms that you need to treat. You had in mind probably - a more short way? Not that I know. The only approach that seems me reasonable is to help Mma a bit. For example, calculate the derivative of a single term on the screen without doing the summation `expr2=D[expr1,f[i]]`. Then see, if the summation is still necessary, and do it, if yes.

Comment: Well the core of the Problem to me is, that I actually dont now how to set a variable index.
f[i] gets symbolized in the evaluation of D[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100}], f[i]]. I would rather use i as a variable that takes on some specific values, according to some rules that I define. Without changing the functions.

Comment: Exactly this I tried to propose. Instead of differentiating `Sum[expr[f[i]],{i,1,100}]]`, you can differentiate the term of the sum: `D[expr[f[i]], f[i]]`. This yields the desired result in your case. In your example `expr[f[i]]=f[i]` but in general, it may be any function of `f[i]`. If you have a double summation or another more complex expression, you may need to later still calculate a sum. But do it after you have already calculated the derivative.

Comment: Again thank you for your patience, but I think i still misunderstand you. Take f.e.
f[x[1]_,x[2]_,x[3]_]:=...
If I want to solve Solve[f[.],x[i]], i\elem Positive Integers <2, I can still not use a variable index. This seems to be a crucial feature.

Comment: No this is impossible. The reason is simple. In your last code you have `Solve[f[x[1],x[2] ]==0,x[i] ]`. That is, the left-hand part of the equation, `f[x[1],x[2] ]` depends on `x[1]` and `x[2] `. Mma, however, will look for its dependence on `x[i]` in the explicit form. And it will not find such. Hence, the result will be "No solution". If instead you try `Solve[f[x[i],x[j] ]==0,x[i] ]` it will work.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!